# A risk of string copy

Tags: c++

I just study c/c++ string using MS'Visual Studio 2013, And find a question about function strcpy_s.
I find that even one don't give a dest char* enough memory,you can use strcpy_s  successfully.Is there any risk using like this?

code:

```
const char* s5 = "hello!";
char* cs6 = new char[1];
strcpy_s(cs6, strlen(s5) + 1, s5);
cs6[2] = 'g';
string s7(cs6);
cout << "----------cs6------------" << endl;
cout << s7 << endl;
```

display in console:

```
----------cs6------------
heglo!
```

Comment: this is undefined behavior. you are writing to memory location which is not belong to your program.  it can run normally in some cases and can crush in other cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And find a question about function strcpy_s. I find that even one don't give a dest char* enough memory,you can use strcpy_s successfully.Is there any risk ...?

Not if you use `strcpy_s` correctly, like this:

```
int buffer_size = 1; // this is silly since null terminated buffer 
                     // of size 1 can only fit a string of length 0
char* cs6 = new char[buffer_size];
strcpy_s(cs6, buffer_size, s5);
cs6[buffer_size - 1] = '\0';
```

The code above is perfectly safe. However:

> Is there any risk using like this?
>
> ```
> const char* s5 = "hello!";
> char* cs6 = new char[1];
> strcpy_s(cs6, strlen(s5) + 1, s5);
> ```

Yes, there is risk. The behaviour is undefined. Best case scenario: The program crashes. Worse scenario: A blackhat hacker exploits the behaviour and steals your data that you were bound by law to not leak.

Comment: Oh! I see.Thank you very much!~

Comment: I'd like to add that the risks involved with potential buffer overflow vulnerabilities is one of the reasons why you should always prefer to use `std::string` (since you're using C++ and have the option to do that) over "c-strings".